# Sending Data in Body in retrofit kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am using retrofit for calling the API i have to send the data in Body as we send in Java @Body but don't know how to parse the data...

```
 {
 "appType": "EXTERNAL",
 "appDetails":{
   "os": "MAC_OSX",
   "osVersion": "1.2",
   "appVersion": "1.0",
   "deviceFamily": "MOBILE",
   "ipAddress": "192.168.5.2"
 },
 "consumerSections":[
   "Support",
   "English",
   "other"
 ],
 "engagementAttributes": [
   {
     "type": "personal",
     "personal": {
       "contacts": [{"email":"test.com","phone":"12345678"},{"email":"test2.co.il","phone":"98765430"}],
       "age": {
         "age":30.0,
         "year":1985,
         "month":7,
         "day":22
       },
       "firstname": "test",
       "lastname": "test2",
       "gender": "FEMALE",
       "company": "liveperson"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

in the API call, how can i parse it and send data to the server.
Please tell....

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send plain json, you could do:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("login")
fun getUser(@Body body: String) : Call<User>
```

If you want automatically cast you kotlin data class, add

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

And then, just set your object with @Body annot.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("login")
fun getUser(@Body body: YourCustomDataObject) : Call<User>
```

[Here is](https://medium.com/@elye.project/kotlin-and-retrofit-2-tutorial-with-working-codes-333a4422a890) an example how to connect all your retrofit2 and service interface together.

Comment: Hey i know how to define it in the Interface but don't know how to parse and send data to server make request....or you can say how to pass the value to the body i mean create a request...hope u understand

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Add the below code in apiService Class:
  @POST("login")
    fun user_login(@Query("role") role: String?, @Body user_registering: RequestBody?): Call<LoginUserResponse?>?

 2. call below func for requestBody:

 private fun callLogIn2(type: String, email: String, password: String) {
    binding.loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    try {
        jsonObject.put("login_id", email)
        jsonObject.put("password", password)
        jsonObject.put("fcm_id",Prefs.getPrefInstance()!!.getValue(this@Login, Const.FCM_ID, ""))
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    val params = jsonObject.toString()
    val user_logging_in = params.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())
    APIUtils.getAPIService()?.user_login(type, user_logging_in)
        ?.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginUserResponse?> { override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginUserResponse?>,
                                                                                  response: Response<LoginUserResponse?>
        ) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                if (response.body()!!.getStatus() != null && response.body()!!.getStatus()!!.equals(200)) {
                    if (response.body()!!.getData()?.get(0)!!.getPaymentStatus() == true) {
                        if (binding.rememberMe.isChecked()) {
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance()!!
                                .setValue(this@Login, Const.PASSWORD, password)
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance()!!
                                .setValue(this@Login, Const.KEEP_USER_LOGGED_IN, "1")
                        } else {
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance()!!.setValue(this@Login, Const.PASSWORD, "")
                            Prefs.getPrefInstance()!!.setValue(this@Login, Const.KEEP_USER_LOGGED_IN, "0") 
                        }
                             if (isCustomer!!) startActivity(
                            Intent(this@Login, MainActivity::class.java).putExtra("isCustomer", true)
                        ) else 
                            startActivity(Intent(this@Login, MainActivity::class.java).putExtra("isCustomer", false))
                    } else {
                        binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                    }
                } else {
                    binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                }
            } else {
                binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            }
        }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginUserResponse?>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
                binding.loader.setVisibility(View.GONE)

            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you post method recive in the body a parameter for example {"name":"pedro"}

you must crate a dataclass

data class myPostMethodBody(
val name: String
)

and y the post interface method

@POST("myPostMethod")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
suspend fun myPostMethod(@Body body: myPostMethodBody
): List